# How to deserialize json property to class property?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

**My JSON file**

```
    [
      {
        "amount":"1000000.0",
        "check_number":1,
        "payment_number":5,
        "attachments":[
          {
            "id":5324,
            "url":"http://www.example.com/",
            "filename":"january_receipt_copy.jpg"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

**My Class File**

```
public class Attachment
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string filename { get; set; }
}

public class AccountDetail
{
    public string amount { get; set; }
    public int check_number { get; set; }
    public int payment_number { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public AccountDetail accountdetail{ get; set; }
    public List<Attachment> attachments { get; set; }
}
```

> Now I want to map JSON file's properties **'check_number','amount'** etc
>   to **accountdetail** by using newtonsoft JSON deserialization.

Comment: Show the code that you have tried and tell us what went wrong?

Comment: @un-lucky:var listRootObject= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(response.ToS‌​tring()); here my response equals to json file which is shown above.when i am access listRootObject.accountdetail is giving null but i want to map accountdetail property with json files 'check_number','amount' property.

Answer (score 4):

You need the following two classes:

```
public class Attachment
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("filename")]
    public string Filename { get; set; }
}

public class AccountDetails
{
    [JsonProperty("amount")]
    public string Amount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("check_number")]
    public int CheckNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("payment_number")]
    public int PaymentNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("attachments")]
    public IList<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

By defining the above classes you can deserialize your json as below:

```
var accountsDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<AccountDetails>>(json);
```

Comment: var listRootObject= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(response.ToS‌​‌​tring()); here my response equals to json file which is shown above.when i am access listRootObject.accountdetail is giving null but i want to map accountdetail property with json files 'check_number','amount' property.