# JSON uses C# keywords

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON schema (from ADP) that has parts of its JSON that looks like this:

```
...
"noteIndicator" : {
          "description" : "True indicates that the System of Record supports the user entering notes / comments.  If the value is false then the notes / comments field will not be visible in the UI",
          "type" : "boolean",
          "optional" : true,
          "default" : false
        }
```

When I use a JSON to C# converter, "default" gets marked as a keyword in C# rather than a field name. Is there anyway I can use an attribute or otherwise make the C# compiler not look at the word "default" as a keyword, but a field name? Is the answer as simple as changing the word "default" to something else?

Comment: You didn't show the C# part where it gets marked. If you doing it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45095157/1997232), then note what `JsonPropertyAttribute` does, then you can indeed change the name of property to something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefix the names (variables, properties or fields) that conflict in your C# code with `@`.

Comment: [Json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) will automatically do this for you.