# How to Serialize/Deserialize Swagger Json To/From C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, swagger, swashbuckle

Swagger Json is malformed in the sense that it cannot be serialized or deserialized in many languages because it allows for properties with illegal variable names such as forward slash. Take this common example from the Swagger website:

http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json

If you copy and past the json in to this common Json -> C# converter, you get an error. Try it out:

http://json2csharp.com/

It kind of works here:
https://www.freecodeformat.com/json2csharp.php

But, this is the C# that is generated:

```
public class Paths
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public /pet /pet { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public /pet/findByStatus /pet/findByStatus { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public /pet/findByTags /pet/findByTags { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public /pet/{petId} /pet/{petId} { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public /pet/{petId}/uploadImage /pet/{petId}/uploadImage { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public /store/inventory /store/inventory { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public /store/order /store/order { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public /store/order/{orderId} /store/order/{orderId} { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public /user /user { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public /user/createWithArray /user/createWithArray { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public /user/createWithList /user/createWithList { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public /user/login /user/login { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public /user/logout /user/logout { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public /user/{username} /user/{username} { get; set; }
}
```

Note: it is totally malformed.

**Is there a way to get this stuff in and out of an object model without resorting to trawling through the object model with Newtonsoft's JObjects etc.?**

Comment: [JsonPropertyAttribute Class](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) You could also use a custom converter

Comment: My question was: Is there a way to get this stuff in and out of an object model without resorting to trawling through the object model with Newtonsoft's JObjects etc.?

Comment: Yeah. Decorate the class with the attribute to map  `/pet` data to `Pet` or whatever you want.  Its a deserializing aide not a parsing thing.    Example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45095063/1070452 With your own converter you could do it yourself.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. Do you want to write that up with a bit more detail so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: You could just dupe it to that link - I am not *certain* is will work with that JSON.  It works to mask out other keywords like return or Error (vb).

Comment: That link doesn't answer my question specifically. You should document it and grab the rep.

Comment: Perhaps `paths` should be deserialized to a `Dictionary<string, PathData>` for some appropriate `PathData`?  See [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536564/3744182).

Comment: swashbuckle does exactly that! have you looked into it?

Comment: Here is what you need:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Core/Swagger/SwaggerDocument.cs