# What [JsonProperty] used for in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, json

For example, why is it needed on below code, how can it further be being used?

```
public class FileAttachment
{
    [JsonProperty("fileName")]
    public string FileName{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm or https://stackoverflow.com/q/45095063/1070452

Comment: In this specific case, it's useless anyway. The default `camelCase` serializer will already serialize to/from `fileName` and not `FileName`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm): this is the json key that will be used when serializing/deserializing this object to/from a json string.

So, if the value of `FileName` is `file.txt`, the serialized result would be

```
{
    "fileName": "file.txt"
}
```